# hiding a particular element of a row using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a array of div elements as follows:-

```
var accdata = [];
for(var i = 0;i < returndata1.length;++i){
accdata.push(
<div className="data-main" onMouseEnter={this.toggleHover} onMouseLeave={this.toggleHover}>
    <span className="data-child">{returndata1[i].Project}</span>
    <span className={this.state.cls}>
        <span className="flag"></span>
        <span className="share"></span>
        <span className="star"></span>                  
    </span>
</div>
);
}
```

```
//toggle function
toggleHover(){
    this.setState({hover: !this.state.hover})
    if(this.state.hover === true){
        this.setState({cls: 'icon-display'})
    }
    else{
        this.setState({cls: ''})
    }
}
```

but on mouseover the span element of all the divisions disappears. how can I set like if we mouseover a particular row only the span element of that row disappears?

Comment: I don't see any array. Please provide a **complete** but minimal example. Also keep in mind that IDs must be **unique** throughout the page.

Comment: I am sorry. Now I have posted my latest code. I removed the id.

Comment: You have to remember the index of the hovered row somewhere / somehow and only apply the class to that row.This might be a good opportunity to encapsulate this div into a new component.

Comment: If I were you, I would apply 'cls' as a state variable to each element of accdata array and remember their states. Then in the onMouseLeave function, pick up the element's index and change it's own cls state accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is using css. Here's an example using some generic css classes: http://jsfiddle.net/9utga8ya/2/

React:

```
var accdata = [];
for(var i = 0;i < returndata1.length;++i){
    accdata.push(
        <div className="data-main">
            <span className="data-child">{returndata1[i].Project}</span>
            <span className="icon-display">
                <span className="flag"></span>
                <span className="share"></span>
                <span className="star"></span>                  
            </span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

CSS:

```
.data-main .icon-display {
    display: inline;
}

.data-main:hover .icon-display {
    display: none;
}
```